# How to fix the error warning failed to connect to lvmetad falling back to internal scanning

Tags: boot, grub2, gui, bootloader, boot-repair

My computer recently started giving me an error right after I installed gnome. It said:

```
WARNING: failed to connect to lvmetad. Falling back to internal scanning
```

I need help to fix the error.

Comment: Just put the disk in and, during install, format everything. However, if you tell us what is actually wrong it might be pretty easy to fix. If you want to just reinstall then, by all means, drop the disk in, boot to it, and install like normal. You can actually keep your /home partition and retain some of your data if you don't format it.

Comment: There are like three open questions about that, right now, from a few users. Did you just recently install Gnome?

Comment: Well, I'd advise one to be patient and hopefully someone will come along and help with the initial problem in a short amount of time. I don't know how to fix it, I don't generally use Gnome. Otherwise, just install it like normal and format the partitions during the install process and all will be good.

Comment: Related: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/199164/error-run-lvm-lvmetad-socket-connect-failed-no-such-file-or-directory-but

Comment: Related Debian bug: https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=792002

Comment: I just got this error at boot time on a freshly-installed and updated (and otherwise working) Xubuntu 16.10. None of the answers or comments so far seem to relate to this circumstance. The installation went without error, and I did not install Gnome.

Comment: I had this warning after a bumpy upgrade to Ubuntu 18.04. The warning was printed at least a dozen times, but after some time the system booted. Then I executed "sudo dpkg-reconfigure lvm2" because it is obviously an LVM problem, and at the next reboot, the problem didn't occur anymore.

Answer (score -2):

Download Ubuntu from [here](http://www.ubuntu.com/download). If your computer was made in the past 8 years then you probably want the 64 bit version. If not then use the 32 bit version.

If you do not know how to make a bootable disk then click [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BurningIsoHowto). I prefer to use `unetbootin` with USB which can be downloaded from [here](http://unetbootin.github.io/). If you use the USB method then make sure to use a partition on the drive that is smaller than 4 GB and is FAT32.

Insert the disk into the tray or the USB drive into the port. Reboot and select to boot to that device. Go ahead and let it boot to the normal live session. Click on the desktop icon to install Ubuntu.

Somewhere, around the 7th step as I recall, you're given an option. The option reads "Erase disk and install Ubuntu." Select that, instead of selecting "something else." This will completely wipe the entire system and give you a brand new starting point per your request.

Comment: Not realistically, no. I've edited the answer to tell you how to get the .ISO and how to use the .ISO.